# Deploy exe from AD with elevated Privileges

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, user-management, sophos

I am trying to deploy the Sophos SSL VPN client to a group of AD users. The SSL client AND the user specific configuration file both require elevated privileges to install.

There is no official MSI from Sophos for the user configs or the client.

I have limited Windows experience so maybe I am not asking the right questions but I need a way to allow standard users to install the client configs without granting them elevated privileges. Is this possible?

Comment: No, not really.  Logon scripts run in user context.  Sounds like you're approaching the problem wrong, though.  Deploying software through a logon script or GPO is a bad idea... and I'm hard pressed to come up with a Sophos product that requires a unique exe for each user and has no better deployment options.  Maybe you should add more details about what you're trying to do.... there's got to be a better way.

Comment: @HopelessN00b  The sophos product is the ssl vpn -  I can edit in more details.